# Is Anthony William's "C++ Concurrency in action" a proper book if not using C++11?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11

I am willing to learn more from concurrency, and I have found this book which has many good reviews. But after taking a look at the preface, I fear that it is very focused on STD functions included only in C++11.

Since C++11 is not very used yet, and not at all at my work place, I need to know if reading this book will be a waste of time when I should be reading a different one.

I'm focusing on Windows development, but I liked the use of standard libraries to be used in UNIX and Windows both. Any recommendation or aclaration about this book?

Comment: It is a proper book, obviously. And no: reading about c++11 isn't a waste of time. If your office doesn't adopt c++11 within a year, staying there would be a waste of your time (in my humble opinion)

Comment: @sehe you probably are right. Unfortunately for me, I am in Spain. There are not many other places to go but abroad.

Comment: @sehe: that depends on lots of things. If you want to refactor your code base with lots of exciting new language features, of course you should have a schedule to move to C++11 (although I doubt it will be implemented within a year, so it depends also how you feel about programming to a moving target). Some products demand a stable toolchain, though, to the point of not taking non-bugfix updates unless strictly necessary.

Comment: @sehe In which case, you'll not be staying in any serious firm.  In practice, if you need to target more than one platform (and cannot restrict yourself to a single compiler), you can't count on using new features for at least five years after they have been officially adapted.  Sometimes more: see `export`.

Comment: @James: somehow you decided I meant 'switch to c++11 exclusively'. I don't see how I implied that? The point I was making was mainly that it is _never_ a waste of time to stay up-to-date. Even if the application lags a bit due to ... reality concerns :) And yes, I'll be 15 years with the same, serious, firm in a month. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JamesKanze: However "serious" the firm you happen to be working for, it seems rather short-sighted to restrict your knowledge to the bare minimum required to comply with their processes. (Although I'm probably not in a position to comment, having spent my career escaping from firms that tried to become too serious.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I definitely agree.  You should always try to stay ahead of what you're currently doing or using.  I'm only reacting to the statement "If your office doesn't adopt c++11 within a year, staying there would be a waste of your time."  There are many reasons why a well organized shop would not adopt C++11 in the next year or two.

Comment: @JamesKanze yeah. Chief among which, if they don't use C++ :)

Comment: @sehe: We are transiting from g++3.4.2 to g++4.3.2 since a couple of years (yes, transiting for a couple of years), wanna work with us :) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM: if you're going to spend a couple of years transitioning, then surely you might as well claim it's deliberate. Just say that you're in a "continual process of adopting the best available tools and practices". And that you're planning to adopt C++11. In about 2027 ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, book heavily uses C++11 syntax.

Also things discussed in book arent just C++11 library features, for example C++11 memory model is a brand new thing in C++11(c++98 did not recognize existence of MT).

Still IMHO you should get a super easy to install g++4.9+boost from : nuwen.net or just get VS 2013 Community.

Because C++11 is the standard and I guess soon youll start using it at your workplace (if not  to quote Andrei Alexandrescu: "Call your headhunter!"). Btw `std::thread` and `boost::thread` are quite similar but with notable differences.

Comment: Don't count VC++2012 Express, because it will install on Windows 8 only.

Comment: @SChepurin : That's only applicable to VS Express for Windows 8; VS Express for Windows Desktop will be available later this year, and does not have that requirement (installs on Vista+ AFAIK).

Comment: @ildjarn - Thank you for correction. It is really a good news and seems to be true according to this thread -http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2645679-visual-studio-11-express-on-windows-7-and-the-abil?page=4

Answer (score 6):

You are right it focuses heavily on C++11. It's "practical multithreading", as the subtitle suggests.

The only way it might interest you if you don't use C++11 is if you plan to use boost threads, which is the base of C++11 threads. But you have to know they are not exactly the same, as C++11 made some changes. ( for instance in C++11 you have to decide wether to wait for your thread to finish or leave it run on its own. In boost it runs on its own by default. If you don't choose in C++11, your program will terminate ).

Then, for your general knowledge as a C++ developper interested in its field, it is a recommended read. C++11 books are not legion for now.

Answer (score 4):

The next generation of Visual C++, which is due out in a whole two weeks, includes `std::thread` libraries, and G++ does already if I'm not mistaken. I wouldn't count this against it. And here's the thing: C++11 is really quite essential. If your workplace isn't planning to migrate, I'd find another workplace.

Comment: g++ 4.6 has threads mutexes and atomics. IDK about older vesions, but either way 4.6 is quite old now anyway ... :)

Comment: "C++11 is really quite essential" - this would be true if no product (or let's be generous to the importance of C++11 threads and say, no multi-threaded product targeting several platforms) had been successfully shipped using previous versions of C++ ;-p

Comment: There's a difference between "planning to migrate" and actually doing it.  From experience, you can't effectively migrate for at least five years after the standard has been adopted.  For that matter, even today, you can't fully use C++98 features, and you have to keep pre-C++98 characteristics in mind if you're worried about portability.  (VC++ 2010, for example, doesn't support C++98 templates.  If Windows is a possible platform, you can't fully migrate to C++98 yet.)

Comment: @James: there's a sort of grey area though, somewhere between "using C++03 with a few common extensions" and "using C++11 but avoiding the features that one or more of your target compilers does not and never will support". As you say, nobody has ever "fully used" C++98 if they use MSVC, GCC, or Intel compilers. AFAIK there has never been an implementation of it (Comeau is close). I expect the same will be true of C++11. So to be sensible, "migrating to C++11" must mean something other than "fully using" it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  In practice, you don't "migrate to C++11", you adopt certain features, little by little.  Some of the new features are pretty trivial, and you can adopt them as soon as all targeted compilers accept them without error (e.g. using `>>` at the end of a nested template).  Others affect code generation, and you don't want to accept them until you're sure that all compilers have gotten them right.  That takes a lot more time: in the places I've worked, the rule has been to let other companies debug the compiler.  C++11's threading is in this category.

Comment: Not really. VS is one of those implementations which has supported threading forever. The Standard threading facilities will simply delegate to their existing libraries. They don't have to implement new code generation capacity to support Standard threads. The few Standard threading features they couldn't rip directly from Boost are available in the PPL. However, there's plenty of important C++11 feature support which is plenty usable in VS2012. Besides, you won't get far *assuming* your implementation is deficient.

Comment: @DeadMG Perhaps, but from what I've heard, VC2012 won't support Windows XP.  And my experience with Microsoft in general (but not only Microsoft) is that it's best to wait for the first couple of patch levels.  Let others debug the compiler.  As for your last statement: you won't get anywhere assuming your implementation is not deficient when it is (and most are, in some way or another).

Comment: Yes, but they're not in most ways. For example, VS2010 had some annoying deficiencies- but they were hardly "make the feature unusable" and overall they functioned quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Since

- you are searching for a book to read on concurrency
- you want to use a library that will work on both windows and unix
- you want to use C++ but not C++11

you would probably need to use Boost.Thread.

There are some reasons why you would read this book then:

- I don't know of a book on Boost threads
- The author of this book has been the primary developer and maintainer of Boost.Thread for years
- C++11 threads are a lot like Boost threads (the author writes: "Most of the examples
  from the book can be modified to work with the Boost Thread Library by judicious
  replacement of std:: with boost:: and use of the appropriate #include directives.")

Answer (score 2):

I think it is very interesting book even if you dont know the multithread things. Like creating two mutexes in the one structure, problems when you switch from two cores to two processors. There is also a lot of design patterns. From this book you will learn in example what is ABA problem and etc. Also boost thread ( which doesnt need c++11x) are very simular to c++11 threads. You will stick with smart_ptrs, maybe sink pattern, RAII and etc. Its a wonderful book.

Be aware that even now not all features are implemented into in example G++. http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Let be honest you sure start learn new c++, its matter of time when you will have to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the book, but if you're not clear about concurrency, then the first thing to do is read about, use and understand *one* multi-threaded system.

Then do the same for another system, and take careful note of the differences from the one you already know. When you discover differences, start to read around to see how lots of different systems handle that aspect of concurrency.

If you're currently working on a multi-threaded program, then the first system you study should be the system you're primarily working on, because until you understand that system's concurrency model, you're probably breaking things and/or programming by copy-and-paste of existing code. So that's likely to be Windows, pthreads, Boost, TBB, or something else that already exists. C++11 could be a strong candidate for the second system, though.

Otherwise, I don't think it makes too much difference which one you study first. OK C++11 has the tiny disadvantage that it doesn't exist yet except as a PDF -- you'll have to install some compiler version that's still in rapid development, and maybe use Boost threads instead of `std::thread` for the time being, and maybe some of the code examples in the book won't compile, and you'll have to work around missing features. So don't try out experiments from the book in your work place on production code (I mean, you wouldn't anyway, right?).

To be honest, never mind C++, learning the *Java* concurrency model could still be a reasonable start on the path towards understanding concurrency. Or Go: that has some very nice abstractions, it will take all of half a day to get the gist of it, and it will show you how you should *want* concurrent programs to work, assuming no ugly complications force you to do otherwise. Sure, you're not going to use all that knowledge from Java, Go or C++11 immediately in your professional C++ work, but it might still be worth having.